# Reversing the mutiple digits in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse

I have problem, where-in I need to take maximum of 10000 test cases as inputs and have 5000 maximum digits and have to reverse the digits.

If suppose I only give 3 testcases and a random no of digits per testcase as below,

n = 3,

```
1] 12 43 => these are the digits => o/P 55
2] 90 235 => o/P is 09 + 532 = 541
3] 23 98899 3454 2323 => o/P is 32 + 99889 + 4543 + 3232 = 107696
```

I need to take these digits as input. Can I take these in an integer array. After storing the digits, I have to reverse the digits and add them.
1] 12 43 can be reversed as 21 34 and added as 21 + 34 = 55. The output is 55

We can reverse a single digit with the below formula,

```
num = 12345
rev_num = 0
while(num > 0) {
  rev_num = (rev_num * 10) + (num%10)
  num = num/10
}
```

But dunno the correct data structure to store it inorder to reverse the multiple digits inputted on a single line and to add the reversed data.
int n;
int (*p)[n];
Cant we have a dynamic declaration of arrays according to the value of n. How to solve this problem.

Comment: How many numbers can be on a line, and how many digits can each number have?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `fgets()` to read the input.
2. Break the input to strings using `strtok()` with space as delimiter.
3. Reverse the string using `strrev()` for each token.
4. Then use `atoi()` to convert the tokens to integers.
5. Once you have the integers perform addition.

Comment: Solid use of c functions

Comment: Maybe you want to mention, `strrev()` is not in standard `c`. It might be available as a compiler extension.

Comment: Thanks Gopi. But I have to code keeping the time complexity and the execution speed in mind. Calling the library functions may eat up the execution time

Comment: *"... 5000 maximum digits ..."* Steps 4 and 5 won't work with that many digits.

Comment: @user3386109 IMO, OP meant 5000 number of `ints` but wrote `digits`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number `(integer)` to `string` then reverse the string and convert back to integer.
To reverse the string, you can use the `strrev()` function.
Note that strrev() is not a standard function and it may not available in standard C library